# Nodejs headers not matching actual request

Tags: node.js, http-headers

There is a problem with NodeJS v7.9.0 where there can be a request

```
curl -i -H Accept:application/json -H range:bytes=1-8 -X GET http://localhost:8080/examples/text.txt
```

However node's request header doesn't match when it is logged

```
console.log(req.headers.range)
```

The logged value varies between different values for the exact same request
(some values logged from that request: bytes=1-2, bytes=1-3, bytes=1-4, bytes=1-5, bytes=1-6, bytes=1, 7 bytes=1-8)

Is this a problem with NodeJS or something else with the computer's setup? And how does one fix it

**Note** the requests are being made with "Rest Web service client" (chrome plugin), and the request above is the equivalent curl command.

Comment: When I remove the "bytes=" part of the range header I don't get the error. Also the numbers are ordered (1-8, 1-7, 1-6, ..., 1-1, 1-8)

Comment: Updated NodeJS to latest (7.10.0), still doesn't work properly